# Python 3+ idiomatic way to hydrate function with args and kwargs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose you have three functions:

```py
def a(x, y, z=0, g=10):
    pass

def b(*args):
    pass

def c(p, q, u=False, *args, **kwargs):
    a(...)
    b(...)
    pass
```

How do I hydrate `c`'s function signature **without** copy pasting every argument and keyword argument, their defaults, etc from sub functions `a`, `b`, etc and automatically filter the appropriate ones to each function? I am *assuming* in this case there are no overloaded keyword arguments i.e. if function `f(...)` has a keyword argument `w` then function `h(...)` does not a keyword argument `w` unless `w` is used the same in `f` and `h`.

Note: I am looking for something like this:

```py
def c(p, q, u=False, *args, **kwargs):
   does_a_have_args, does_a_have_kwargs = get_func_sig_info(a)

   a_args = get_fn_args(a) if does_a_have_args else []
   a_kwargs = get_fn_kwargs(a) if does_a_have_kwargs else []
   
   a_args = get_args_from_self(*args, a_args)
   a_kwargs = get_kwargs_from_self(**kwargs, a_kwargs)

   a(*a_args, **a_kwargs)

   does_b_have_args, does_b_have_kwargs = get_func_sig_info(b)

   b_args = get_fn_args(b) if does_b_have_args else []
   b_kwargs = get_fn_kwargs(b) if does_b_have_kwargs else []
   
   b_args = get_args_from_self(*args, b_args)
   b_kwargs = get_kwargs_from_self(**kwargs, b_kwargs)

   b(*b_args, **b_kwargs)
```

so that I might have a utility function:

```py
def wrangle_function_signature(function, *args, **kwargs):
   does_f_have_args, does_f_have_kwargs = get_func_sig_info(a)

   f_args = get_fn_args(function) if does_f_have_args else []
   f_kwargs = get_fn_kwargs(function) if does_f_have_kwargs else []
   
   f_args = get_args_from_self(*args, f_args)
   f_kwargs = get_kwargs_from_self(**kwargs, f_kwargs)

   return (*f_args, **f_kwargs)
```

making the above pseudocode for `c`:

```
def c(p, q, u=False, *args, **kwargs):
   a_args, a_kwargs = wrangle_function_signature(a, *args, **kwargs)
   a(*a_args, **a_kwargs)

   b_args, b_kwargs = wrangle_function_signature(b, *args, **kwargs)
   b(*b_args, **b_kwargs)

   pass
```

Comment: Do you just need to pass arguments without any binding to objects?

Comment: @gormih in this example I simply want a way to have function arguments for arbitrarily nested functions accessible from higher layers without having an explosively long function signature for high level functions. In practice bindings may be practical / or some custom adjustments.

Comment: For example, you can get the names of all the arguments for a function, and with or without conversion, get their value via dict, right?

Comment: You can use `inspect.getfullargspec` to get everything you need but there are many cases to handle so it's just going to be more work than copy/pasting the arguments... And it's hard to be generic, like what happens if both `a` and `b` have `*args`? Or if they contain `**kwargs`?

Comment: @Holt  hmmm... I see... what if it is the case that each function which accepts `*args` and `**kwargs` handles them appropriately?

Comment: I think the hard part is getting the names of the arguments meant for the sub functions from `*args` in `def c(p, q, u=False, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: If you give us more context, it is likely that we can help find a better solution to the problem that motivated this question. It is an interesting question though.

Comment: @Kapocsi it is literally as described. I tend to write small, singular purpose functions  and then compose larger functions out of them rather than just some `god_function(...)`. When working on a library the higher level functions tend to get a "lot" of arguments for configuration (20+) for these sub functions.  Both the function signature and the associated doc string are just unruly.

Comment: @SumNeuron If you really have such generic setup, then your library is very badly organized and it will be impossible to use higher-level function and their documentation will be tremendously complicated... I just started writing a partial answer to your question and simply gave up because the amount of work and complexity to extract the right positional arguments for the right functions is just over-complicated, meaning that anyone using `c` will have to think very hard to understand what `c` will do with `*args`.

Comment: @Holt I appreciate that you invested time into this question and your expertise. So then, the best solution is the simple one e.g. lift the necessary arguments up if needed.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter.kind

Comment: @Kapocsi it is of interest